# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails SQL error

Tags: python, sql, reactjs

I'm trying to delete the product row using the delete button on y frontend(frontend is in reactjs) but it throws this error message on the python SQL server.
`ysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`grocery_store`.`order_details`, CONSTRAINT` fk_product_id `FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES` products `(`product_id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT)`

delete route code:

```
@app.route('/delete', methods=['POST'])
def delete_product():
    return_id = products_dao.delete_product(connection, request.json["product_id"])
    response = jsonify({
        'product_id': return_id
    })
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    return return_id
```

product_dao.py file code

```
def delete_product(connection, product_id):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = ("DELETE FROM products where product_id={}".format(product_id))
    cursor.execute(query)
    connection.commit()
    return "product deleted"
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Postman Request:
[image]

Comment: This is an SQL issue only, it has nothing to do with react or python.
Anyway, in your case you can't delete a product that exists on order_details. Google the error to find out more.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is self explanatory, you have foreign key references you have to either first delete/update values in the child table and then to parent or use `ON DELETE/UPDATE CASCADE` which will automatically do the same

Comment: Hello Himanshu, I'm very new to SQL. Can you please give me an example of `ON DELETE/UPDATE CASCADE` how to implement this?
When I run the file manually from the terminal and call that function, it deletes the product without any error.

Comment: From your error lines, i could see there are values in your orderdetails table for the same productid which is already present in your product table. So, you have to first delete those records via `delete from orderdetails where productid=<>` then the same above will work. But again i would say depends upon your requirement check if this suits your requirement coz there is `ON UPDATE RESTRICT` though its not for `DELETE` but surely double check

Comment: Is it possible to delete only product without making any changes to the order-details table?

Comment: Its only possible if those products details doesnt exist in order-details table